# How to change the value of a radio button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

This Flutter `RadioButton` is not changing after entering the default value:

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Card(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
myGlobals['${index}'] = "${answer}"!;

return  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),child: RadioListTile(
                          value: "${list[i]}",
                          groupValue: myGlobals['${index}'],
    onChanged: (val){
                            setState(() {myGlobals['${index}'] = "${list[i]}";});
                            _onUpdateInput(index, question_id, question, val.toString());},
                          title: Text("${list[i]}"),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```

Comment: hi , this code is incomplete and even the type of values used in it is not clear. Please attach the reproducible code in your question.

Comment: Try my radio group package https://pub.dev/packages/radio_group_v2

Answer (score 0):

Import this Package for the radio button [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/group_radio_button)

```
import 'package:group_radio_button/group_radio_button.dart';
```

add group_radio_button to pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
  sdk: flutter      
  group_radio_button: ^1.3.0
```

Multiple Radio Groups

```
RadioGroup<String>.builder(
  groupValue: _verticalGroupValue,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
  _verticalGroupValue = value;
 }),
 items: _status,
 itemBuilder: (item) => RadioButtonBuilder(
  item,
  ),
 ),
```